# I send tcp syn packet to a Ip that does not exist，but don't get response

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I write tcp syn portscan in c
When i send tcp syn to a exist ip ,it works well
But when i send to a ip that does not exist,the function sendto()<0 doesn't works , what the problems?

I use codeblocks and gcc on ubuntu18

This is part of the code

```
//Create a raw socket
  int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);

//IP_HDRINCL to tell the kernel that headers are included in the packet
  int one = 1;
  const int *val = &one;
  setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (one);

// send syn packet
   if ( sendto (s, datagram, sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dest, sizeof (dest)) < 0){
  {
            printf ("Error sending syn packet. Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n",errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }}
```

When i debug to see the return of sendto(),it's -1，
but if(sendto()<0) doesn't works,

Answer (score 0):

You only get a -1  return value for locally detected errors, once the packet is out on the net, sendto is done with it.

[man sendto](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto)

> No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a send(). Locally
>   detected errors are indicated by a return value of -1.

```
// send syn packet
size_t ret_code = sendto (s,datagram, 
                         sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr),
                         0,(struct sockaddr *) &dest, sizeof (dest)) ;
// ret_code will be length if successful, else -1      

if ( ret_code ==-1){
        // If packet successfully sent out on interface but dropped by router along path, this is not triggered.
        printf ("Error sending syn packet. Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n",errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: why not exit(0)?

Comment: because sendto doesn't return -1 as it was able to send the packet out on the network interface.